# Both double tap and tap-to-zoom

Tags: iphone, ipad, coding-style, zooming, tap

Im trying to make an ebook or an app for iPad at my work, which can allow the user to both double tap to zoom and from there pinch to zoom further. The double tap to zoom needs to have the effect that the picture goes from being a small picture to a fullscreen picture. When the picture is fullscreen, I want the user to have the opportunity to pinch to zoom at the fullscreen image. Just like you can on facebook.

But I don't know how to do this. I have tried several programs, and I'm almost giving up, but I can't, 'cause it's a part of my internship at a museum in Denmark, Europe. I have no budget.

I have been working in InDesign and iBooks Author. And I haven't found a solution yet. So therefore I'm asking for your help. I really hope you can help me. Can you please link to tutorial or a free program which can do what I (and the users) really want? Or maybe you have some really nice advices.

Thanks in advance
Mvh Julie, Denmark

Answer (score 0):

To Detect double tap add TAPGesture in your view and to zoom (detect pinch to zoom)  add Pinchtozoom gesture...

Comment: Are you referring to something you can do in xCode?
I'm currently not working in xCode, 'cause I can't find my way around it. I have been trying to solve my problem in Indesign, iBooks Author, Powerpoint, Keynote, Flowboard ect.
I haven't found a solution yet, unfortunately.

Comment: You can refer [This link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html)...